# Stored procedure weird error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

In SQL Server 2016, a stored procedure is throwing an error when it's executed from my .Net application. And when we execute the same stored procedure in the database with the same input parameters, there is no error.

After altering the stored procedure without changing any logic, it again starts work normally for sometime. Frequently we are facing this issue.

Any suggestion to fix this issue permanently?

Comment: Could you please add at least the code in your application, where you SP is called and the Name and parameters of the SP?

Comment: And the Error would be good to know.

Comment: @Nikolaus Unfortunately we do not have any error log. Just executing the same SP with Alter statement resolves the issue. So I thought this is Database or SP issue.

Comment: If you don't have an error, why is your title "weird error"? If there's no error, it can't be weird.

Comment: One obvious potentially problematic scenario is if the error is a timeout; this would mean a bad execution plan gets cached for your stored procedure. An `ALTER` forces a recompile. If the error is not a timeout, however, things get a lot more interesting. We really do need to know, at the very least, what error you're getting -- if you have no logs, set it up so you can get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ran into the same exact thing. The stored proc ran fine in the db but took forever or timed out when ran from the app. 
In the end it came down to parameter sniffing and having bad plans in the cache. The quick and dirty fix is to recompile the stored proc using the '[with recompile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/recompile-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017)' option. We eventually just re-wrote the proc.

Anyways, [this article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/) is very good at explaining how SQL Server uses parameter sniffing, why it is a good thing until it is not.

Happy hunting!